# How to solve the RecylerView error in Android SDK?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing this code to create a material Navigation bar. The error is `cannot resolve a RecylerView` in the line of code:

```
   mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

the error is coming on the RecyclerView present in the R.id.RecyclerView. My android api is 23 and android sdk version is 1.5.1.

#### NavigationBar.java

```
package srk.materialdesignnavigationbar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class NavigationBar extends ActionBarActivity {


   String TITLES[]={"HOME","EVENTS","MAIL","SHOP","TRAVEL"};
    int ICONS[] = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher};

    String NAME ="surya ramiah";
    String EMAIL="suryaramiah1996@gmail.com";
    int PROFILE = R.drawable.s;

    private   Toolbar toolbar;

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    DrawerLayout Drawer;

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_bar);

        toolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

 }
```

#### Gradle

```
 build.gradle(Module:app)
    {

        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0-alpha2'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: cannot resolve symbol  RecyclerView

Comment: Please include the layout file *activity_navigation_bar.xml* and the complete stack trace of the error. It is still not completely clear to me whether you are talking about a *build error* or a *run time exception*.